# Mobile Safari & Chrome - ontimeupdate not functioning, working in desktop

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari, mobile-chrome

I have built a solution that overlays text on to a video background which is timed to the video, this work really well in desktop browsers however in my mobile browser testing (iOS 15 (Safari) and Android 11 (Chrome) the javascript does not seem to fire.

I have checked the MDN docs and caniuse.com and both say that `ontimeupdate` is supported, having looked at the questions on stack I cannot find a solution that works for what I need to do, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
const medicalTextOverlay = document.getElementById('medicalTextOverlay');
const medicalVideoPlayer = document.getElementById('medicalVideo');
const medicalVideoCounter = document.getElementById("medicalVideoCounter");
let medicalVideoText = document.querySelectorAll('.medical-text-item');
let medicalVideoTotalTimePlayed = 0;
let medicalVideoLastUpdatedTime = 0;
medicalVideoPlayer.ontimeupdate = (event) => {
    var newTime = medicalVideoPlayer.currentTime;
    var timeDiff = newTime - medicalVideoLastUpdatedTime;
    if (timeDiff > 0) {
        medicalVideoTotalTimePlayed += timeDiff;
        var index = 0, length = medicalVideoText.length;
        for ( ; index < length; index++) {

            if (medicalVideoText[index].classList.contains('animate__fadeOut')) {
                medicalVideoText[index].classList.remove('animate__fadeOut');
            }

            let itemShow = medicalVideoText[index].getAttribute('data-video-timecode-show');
            let itemHide = medicalVideoText[index].getAttribute('data-video-timecode-hide');
            if (newTime >= itemShow) {
                medicalVideoText[index].classList.add('show');
                medicalVideoText[index].classList.add('animate__fadeIn');
            }

            if (newTime >= itemHide) {
                medicalVideoText[index].classList.remove('animate__fadeIn');
                medicalVideoText[index].classList.add('animate__fadeOut');
                medicalVideoText[index].classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
    medicalVideoLastUpdatedTime = newTime;
};
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #000;
}
.lhg-main #medicalTextOverlay {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 60vw;
    height: 60vh;
    display: block;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    font-family: "acumin-pro-wide";
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 0.8;
    background: transparent
}

.lhg-main #medicalTextOverlay .medical-text-item {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0 !important;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-stretch: extra-condensed;
    letter-spacing: -0.0625rem;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out
}

.lhg-main #medicalTextOverlay .medical-text-item.show {
    opacity: 1 !important
}

.lhg-main #medicalTextOverlay .medical-text-item:nth-child(1) {
    top: 2rem;
    left: 0rem
}

.lhg-main #medicalTextOverlay .medical-text-item:nth-child(2) {
    top: 2rem;
    left: 1rem
}

.lhg-main #medicalTextOverlay .medical-text-item:nth-child(3) {
    top: 2rem;
    left: 1rem
}

.lhg-main #medicalTextOverlay .medical-text-item:nth-child(4) {
    top: 2rem;
    left: 1rem
}

.lhg-main #medicalTextOverlay .medical-text-item:nth-child(5) {
    top: 2rem;
    left: 1rem
}

.lhg-main #medicalTextOverlay .medical-text-item:nth-child(6) {
    top: 2rem;
    left: 1rem
}

.lhg-main #medicalTextOverlay .medical-text-item:nth-child(7) {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 6rem;
    letter-spacing: -0.125rem;
    top: 7rem;
    left: -1rem
}

.lhg-main #medicalTextOverlay .medical-text-item:nth-child(8) {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 6rem;
    letter-spacing: -0.125rem;
    top: 7rem;
    left: -1rem
}

.lhg-main #medicalTextOverlay .medical-text-item:nth-child(9) {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 6rem;
    letter-spacing: -0.125rem;
    top: 7rem;
    left: -1rem
}

.lhg-main #medicalTextOverlay .medical-text-item:nth-child(10) {
    top: 2rem;
    left: 1rem
}

.lhg-main #medicalTextOverlay .medical-text-item:nth-child(11) {
    top: 2rem;
    left: 1rem
}

.lhg-main #medicalTextOverlay .medical-text-item:nth-child(12) {
    top: 2rem;
    left: 1rem
}

.lhg-main #medicalTextOverlay .medical-text-item:nth-child(13) {
    top: 2rem;
    left: 1rem
}

.lhg-main #medicalTextOverlay .medical-text-item:nth-child(14) {
    top: 2rem;
    left: 1rem
}
```

```html
<main class="lhg-main" id="medicalOverlay">
  <div id="medicalTextOverlay">
    <div class="medical-text-item animate__animated animate__slow" data-video-step="1" data-video-timecode-show="02.01" data-video-timecode-hide="04.02">To create something meaningful</div>
    <div class="medical-text-item animate__animated animate__slow" data-video-step="2" data-video-timecode-show="04.03" data-video-timecode-hide="07.15">memorable and affect change</div>
    <div class="medical-text-item animate__animated animate__slow" data-video-step="3" data-video-timecode-show="07.16" data-video-timecode-hide="11.19">you must elicit a reaction.<br/>Evoke an involuntary response.</div>
    <div class="medical-text-item animate__animated animate__slow" data-video-step="5" data-video-timecode-show="11.20" data-video-timecode-hide="15.07">Ignite a spark.</div>
    <div class="medical-text-item animate__animated animate__slow" data-video-step="6" data-video-timecode-show="15.08" data-video-timecode-hide="19.13">Through exceptional science, artfully delivered,</div>
    <div class="medical-text-item animate__animated animate__slow" data-video-step="7" data-video-timecode-show="19.14" data-video-timecode-hide="22.18">our expert team knows how to elicit<br/>a real human reaction</div>
    <div class="medical-text-item animate__animated animate__slow" data-video-step="8" data-video-timecode-show="22.19" data-video-timecode-hide="24.22">intellectual</div>
    <div class="medical-text-item animate__animated animate__slow" data-video-step="9" data-video-timecode-show="24.23" data-video-timecode-hide="27.04">emotional</div>
    <div class="medical-text-item animate__animated animate__slow" data-video-step="10" data-video-timecode-show="27.05" data-video-timecode-hide="30.06">visual.</div>
    <div class="medical-text-item animate__animated animate__slow" data-video-step="11" data-video-timecode-show="30.07" data-video-timecode-hide="34.28">Our partners come back to us again and again</div>
    <div class="medical-text-item animate__animated animate__slow" data-video-step="12" data-video-timecode-show="34.29" data-video-timecode-hide="39.07">to harness the power of Spark theory</div>
    <div class="medical-text-item animate__animated animate__slow" data-video-step="13" data-video-timecode-show="39.08" data-video-timecode-hide="44.00">Let us help you elicit a reaction,<br>evoke a response</div>
    <div class="medical-text-item animate__animated animate__slow" data-video-step="14" data-video-timecode-show="44.01" data-video-timecode-hide="48.19">and spark change.</div>
  </div>
  <video poster="https://assets.codepen.io/32795/poster.png" preload="metadata" id="medicalVideo" autoplay="1" loop="1" muted class="background-video desktop">
                        <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        <source src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.webm" type="video/web"for_desktop">
                        <source src="/assets/video/http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.ogv" type="video/ogv">
                    </video>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

This turend out to be a duplicate ID problem where the `<video>` tag had been duplicated later in the code.